# the meaning of flag as a verb and interest in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm interested in the meaning of *flag* as a verb and *interest* in this sentence:

> Variables can be extracted from social media content that flag an interest, emotion, or attitude of the contributor.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flag_2

does "interest" mean "people likes" here???

Comment: I would think that it means what it usually means, ie something that the person is interested in.

Comment: It means *people are interested in*. You may be *interested* in things you don't necessarily *like*. But should rather ask this question on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `flag` something is to mark it as something. You can flag comments that you find offensive, funny, useful etc.

Interest has it's usual meaning here.

Also, `does "interest" mean "people likes" here???` is incorrect English. Should be `people's likes`

Contributor is used to refer to the person who makes the comments in question. He who *contributes* those comments.

Comment: so it simply means to mark sth?

Comment: Yes, I would flag your comment as `weak` for example.

Comment: I'm wondering what contributer means here aswell :S.

Comment: So you can flag my comment as `not clear`. Get it now? :)

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/contributor?q=contributor

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought you were referring to me when you said *contributor*. Edited the answer

Comment: can we say that a user of social media is a contributor somehow??? you know because I have to translate this into my own language, and I can't find an equivalent that fits. "Variables can be extracted from social media content that flag an interest, emotion, or attitude of the contributor."

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in my answer. The user of the social network *is* the contributor. Urdu? I like Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan!

Answer (score 0):

The author is referring to content on social media that refer to ('flag') an area of 'interest' (as in 'hobbies & interests' e.g. motorcycles) of the author of the content.

For example a post might say 'My sewing project is going well' - the post 'flags' the 'interest' of sewing.